Problem with add/.style in tkz-euclide
add is a style for changing the start and end points when drawing a line from one node to another.
Its definition is:
\tikzset{add/.style args={#1 and #2}{to path={%
 ($(\tikztostart)!-#1!(\tikztotarget)$) -- ($(\tikztotarget)!-#2!(\tikztostart)$)%
  \tikztonodes}}
} 

The code below illustrates the problem. When the first argument of add is negative, the node \tikztostart is part of the bounding box. This shouldn't happen. This is not the case for the second argument. There's no problem when both arguments are positive.
How can I prevent \tikztostart from being part of the bounding box when the first argument is negative?
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.75]
        \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O,5/0/A,3/4/B}
        \tkzDrawLines[add = -.2 and -.2,thick](O,A O,B)
        \tkzShowBB[blue]
        \tkzDrawPoints(A,B)
        \tkzShowBB[red]
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


I was thinking of getting the green box

For more information, here are the macros involved
\def\tkzDrawLine{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\tkz@DrawLine}{\tkz@DrawLine[]}}
\def\tkz@DrawLine[#1](#2,#3){%    
\begingroup  
   \draw[line style,#1] (#2) to (#3); 
\endgroup
}

\tikzset{%
line style/.style = {%
    line width = \tkz@euc@linewidth,
    color      = \tkz@euc@linecolor,
    style      = \tkz@euc@linestyle,
    add        = {\tkz@euc@lineleft} and    {\tkz@euc@lineright},
    line cap   = round
    }
}


Bit confused about what the problem is supposed to be. Is the red one supposed to be the correct bounding box or the incorrect one? Obviously, the red one is going to include the added stuff, so I guess the issue is supposed to be that the blue box should already include it? But I'm not clear why ...? Or is it that the blue box is too large and should fit the drawn lines tightly?

It would be easier if the example used to first code snippet explicitly. I guess you need to interrupt the bounding box or declare some parts irrelevant for the bounding box? Somewhere in the code which uses the tikztostart.

@cfr Sorry if my question isn't clear! tikztostart is used in  \tkzDrawLines[add = -.2 and -.2,thick](O,A O,B). The boxes shown are all wrong. The blue box on the right is correct: it stops after the straight lines. On the left, there's a "problem" because point O is not drawn, so it's the black lines that should determine the bounding box.

@cfr I added a figure with the box I thought I'd get (green). The problem lies in the definition of to path in the add style.

Thanks. That's very helpful. I kind of guessed that at the end of my comment, but I'd been convinced one of the boxes was meant to be wrong and the other right. (No good reason, probably but unfounded assumption.)

Does to path place actual coordinates for \tkztostart and \tkztotarget? Because the underlying tikz method here doesn't enlarge the bb (as I assume you know).

@cfr  I've added the macros that are useful for completing the question. Apart from to path,  I can't see when the bounding box is modified. It's probably a stupid error that I can't see.  The files concerned are tkz-obj-eu-lines.tex and  tkz-euclide.cfg

Yes, I only meant that simply calculating the coordinates doesn't expand it. So it has to be something about to path, I guess. My suspicion is that the underlying path is independent of the to path options, but why does it work for the target but not the to?

\path (#2) already updates the BB to include the point #2. You're just doing \path (#2) ($(#2)!…!(#3)$) --($(#3)!…!(#2)$);. We need to not update the BB for only (#2). One approach I tried worked but also ignored the line width (which is done at the end, not when the coordinates are scanned).

@Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you for your information and comments !

A to path operation is – at its core – just an expansion of whatever is stored in to path.
That means your path
\draw[line style,#1] (#2) to (#3); 

just becomes
\draw[line style,#1] (#2) ($(#2)!…!(#3)$) -- ($(#3)!…!(#2)$);

This path consists of

a move-to to #2,
a move-to to (#2)!…!(#3) and
a line-to to (#3)!…!(#2).

All these steps update the bounding box. (The intersections and/or the spath library might contain tools to remove the first otherwise pointless move-to but that would be too much for this task.)
We want to eliminate the first move-to or instruct TikZ/PGF to not update the bounding box for this. In my experiments, the latter approach was not immediately successful.

Eliminating the first move-to is easy:
\path to (#3);

is a valid TikZ path. But, of course, TikZ will just fall back to a \tikztostart of 0pt, 0pt which – in your MWE – would accidentally be correct. (I've changed the definition of O in the code below.)
When the TikZ parser encounters a to it just checks whether the last seen coordinate is a node (but not a coordinate) and sets \tikztostart to the node's name. For all other cases it defines \tikztostart to be the values of \tikz@lastx and \tikz@lasty (which are initialized to be 0pt at the start of a path).
But we can just override \tikztostart again:

with the execute at begin to key,
with the every to style or
directly with the options of the to.

This is also the order of their execution:
\pgfextra{\tikz@atbegin@to}%              ← execute at begin to
\pgfextra{\tikz@enable@edge@quotes}
[style=every to]                        % ← every to
  \expandafter[\tikz@@to@local@options] % ← to[<options>]
  \tikz@to@path                         % ← the actual “to path”

All three are included in the code below.
Which you choose seems to be irrelevant except if you have or expect your users to use to paths that include another to or even an edge†: Both \tikz@atbegin@to and every to will be applied again with nested to. The first even with an edge.
I believe, the last one to be the safest.

† Whether nesting tos and edges is a good idea is another topic but it can be done.
Code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\makeatletter
\def\tkz@DrawLine[#1](#2,#3){%
\begingroup
%  \draw[line style,#1, execute at begin to=\def\tikztostart{#2}] to (#3);
%  \draw[line style,#1, every to/.append code=\def\tikztostart{#2}] to (#3);
  \draw[line style,#1] to[/utils/exec=\def\tikztostart{#2}] (#3);
\endgroup}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.75]
\tkzDefPoints{-1/-1/O,5/0/A,3/4/B}
\tkzDrawLines[add = -.2 and -.2,thick](O,A O,B)
\tkzShowBB[blue]
\tkzDrawPoints(O,A,B)
\tkzShowBB[red]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


The solution above will fail
\tkzDrawLines[line to](O,A O,B)

or any other to path that doesn't contain an initial move-to since #2 never actually gets used then.
Since the add key is such an integral part of \tkzDrawLine(s), I'd be inclined to apply these calculations directly.
Then, the user can still use to path to apply its own style to the new start and end points, say:
\tkzDrawLines[add = -.2 and -.2, thick, bend left](O,A O,B)

Code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{add/.code args={#1and#2}{\edef\tkz@euc@lineleft{#1}\edef\tkz@euc@lineright{#2}}}
\def\tkz@DrawLine[#1](#2,#3){%
  \draw[line style,#1] ($(#2)!-(\tkz@euc@lineleft )!(#3)$)
                    to ($(#3)!-(\tkz@euc@lineright)!(#2)$);}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.75]
\tkzDefPoints{-1/-1/O,5/0/A,3/4/B}
\tkzDrawLines[add = -.2 and -.2, thick](O,A O,B)
\tkzShowBB[blue]
\tkzDrawPoints(O,A,B)
\tkzShowBB[red]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

